# Strange behavior of regex

Tags: regex

Background:
I need to identify a pair of numbers separated by a hyphen (-), the numbers can optionally include +/- and can be decimal.
So below are examples of that:

```
3-4, +3-+4, .3-.4, 0.3-0.4, -0.3--0.4, 0.3--0.4 etc...
```

I was using below expression:

```
(-?\+?\d*.?\d*)-(-?\+?\d*.?\d*)
```

It works well in most cases but fails in below:

```
-0.3--0.4
```

The groups it forms are: `-0.3-` and `0.4`

But if i replace it like:
`(-?\+?\d*.?\d+)-(-?\+?\d*.?\d+)`, it works fine.

I am wondering what difference replacing the `*` with `+` is making?

We have used this in javascript.

Comment: `-?+?` allows for `"-+"` to be matched; you probably want `[-+]?`

Comment: `(-?\+?\d*.?\d*)-(-?\+?\d*.?\d*)` works perfectly fine for me for your expected output

Comment: Especially if you have a special case that you claim does not match as expected, you need to identify what language/tool you are using.

Comment: I'd suggest [`([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)-([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/EBQBX6/3) - make at least 1 digit obligatory. Also, allow only one sign before a number with `[-+]?`, and do not allow a `-+` sequence. You also must escape the dot to match a literal dot.

Comment: By "groups", you imply that the first parenthesis group `(-?\+?\d*.?\d*)` matches (i.e. captures) `-0.3-`.  That does not seem possible.  How do you come to determination of which group matches which text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong capturing is accounted for by the fact that your patterns inside capturing groups (`-?\+?\d*.?\d*`) can match an empty string *and* - more importantly here - `.` matches any char, not only a dot. You must escape it to match a literal dot. Note how [`(-?\+?\d*.?\d*)-(-?\+?\d*.?\d*)`](https://regex101.com/r/grdvpD/1) matches `3-4,` (the `,` is captured with Group 2 pattern `.`) and note Matches 5 and 6 where `.` matches a space and a hyphen.

Also, your `-?\+?` actually allows matching `-+` sequence of signs, which does not seem what you need. Just use `[-+]?` optional character class.

So, you might want to use [`([-+]?\d*\.?\d*)-([-+]?\d*\.?\d*)`](https://regex101.com/r/grdvpD/1)  pattern, but I'd advise to make sure at least 1 digit is matched, and you may use [`([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)-([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/EBQBX6/3) pattern for it.

Details:

- `([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 1: a sequence of

  - `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
  - `\.?` - an optional `.`
  - `\d+`/`\d*`   - 1 or more digits (or 0 or more with `*`)
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)` - see above.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This explains, probably it was the unescaped ".", which was causing the issue.